# Double For Loop for finding if a cell value is in a range

Tags: vba, excel

Even more VBA Goodness, i've tried writing a for loop with a for loop to go through get the cells text assign it a a variable and then run through a range seeing if the cells value is in range and if found then change another cells value to yes or no if not found but i keep getting all NO's despite being able seeing the values inside the range myself

The whole point is to avoid using vlookup function =if(vlookup("value","Table","col","false"),"Yes","No") which seems to skip some values despite being present.

my code is

```
Dim xell As Range

For Each xell In Range("C6:C36")

lookFor = xell.Value

For i = 6 To 36

    If Cells(i, 10).Value = lookFor Then
        Cells(i, 7).Value = "Yes"
        Else
        Cells(i, 7).Value = "No"
    End If
Next i

Next xell
```

The idea being loop in the first range get the cells text assign it to a variable and start a new loop during this to look through a range to see if the cell value is inside this range.

It executes but comes back with All no.

Comment: you overwrite your cells each time so only get results for last xcell in Range("C6:C36")

Comment: What would be the correction then?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i had n exited my loop when finding a yes :)

Exit For  was needed

```
Dim xell As Range

For Each xell In Range("C6:C36")

lookFor = xell.Value

For i = 6 To 36

    If Cells(i, 10).Value = lookFor Then
        Cells(i, 7).Value = "Yes"
        Exit For <-------- was missing
        Else
        Cells(i, 7).Value = "No"
    End If
Next i

Next xell
```

Didnt solve my current issue of data not being found unless edited

Comment: OK, now, you solved the overwriting by the "No". But you still have the overwriting by the last loop (xell = C36). The result of that last loop overwrites the results of the 29 previous loops... But this is not a problem of VBA but the problem of design of what you want to do...

Comment: The results of this worked for me, to ensure it did i ran it next to a vlookup which produced the same results even the constant cell which wont be found unless edited was the same